# Coded UI Test Builder fails to generate code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

The coded ui test builder is failed to generate code. i created the new test project and added the coded ui test file. i have chosed the option 1.Record options then the Test builder is running.

when i record the actions and trying to generate code

it is throwing error
 "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Kindly help in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this from the very small amount of information in your question. Searching the web for the error message (eg searching for "coded ui Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and variations) provides many cases of people getting the same message plus, in some cases, their solutions.

One possible cause is that the UI Map file has been edited in a text editor, leaving XML that the Generate tool does not understand. Another possibility is that  Visual Studio has become corrupted and should be reinstalled.

To narrow down the possibilities, determine whether the problem is specific to one project, to one computer or to one user. Try creating a new Coded UI test in a new Visual Studio solution to drive a simple application (eg the Windows Calculator) and see whether the generator works OK. Copy the failing project (and the whole solution) to another computer and see whether code can be generated there. Try logging in as a different user on the same computer and generating code for the same project and for different projects.